# this class is not key value coding-compliant for key

Tags: ios, swift, nsunknownkeyexception

Sorry I do not have specific question but I cannot figure out how to get around this error. The app itself does not show any errors in Xcode but it crashes at start with the error message `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key guessMade.`

```
@IBOutlet weak var numberGuessed: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var answer: UILabel!

@IBAction func guessMade(sender: AnyObject) {

    var numberOfFingers  = arc4random_uniform(11)
    var numberString = String(numberOfFingers)
    var integerGuessed = numberGuessed.text

    if numberString == integerGuessed {
        self.answer.text = "You're right! I had \(integerGuessed) fingers up"
    }else {
        self.answer.text = "Nope! I had \(numberString) fingers up"

    }
}
```

It is a very small project so this is the entire code. The button `guessMade` is supposed to check to see if the number entered in the text field matches the randomly generated number also produced when the button is pressed. Any ideas what the error is telling me wrong?

Comment: Delete all IBOutlet and re-link them again. Have a try.

Comment: Please [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=this+class+is+not+key+value+coding-compliant+for+the+key). This issue has been covered many times.

Comment: @WorldOfWarcraft thank you I somehow had that button linked twice.

Comment: self.answer.text = arc4random_uniform(11).description == numberGuessed.text ? "You're right! I had \(integerGuessed) fingers up" :  "Nope! I had \(numberString) fingers up"

Comment: You can change all those lines of code for a single one. BTW Why do you declare it all as vars if they are constants?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus because the app needs to generate a random number every time the button is pressed and match it with whatever is entered into the text field.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ... This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key)

Answer (score 4):

Inspect your view controllers files owner, such as:

[image]

See if there is anything yellow waring marked like this, if there is anything delete this.
Hope this helps.. :)